# cmake error: "cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++20’; did you mean ‘-std=c++2a’?"

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm attempting to compile a binary from source, but keep running into an error while doing so.

```
$ cmake --build ./\[binary_dir\]/
[  0%] Building C object [binary_dir]/CMakeFiles/ZIPLIB.dir/extlibs/bzip2/bcompress.c.o
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++20’; did you mean ‘-std=c++2a’?
make[2]: *** [[binary_dir]/CMakeFiles/ZIPLIB.dir/build.make:154: [binary_dir]/CMakeFiles/ZIPLIB.dir/extlibs/bzip2/bcompress.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:307: [binary_dir]/CMakeFiles/ZIPLIB.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Specifically, "**cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++20’; did you mean ‘-std=c++2a’?**."

I suspect this has to do with using the incorrect version of gcc; I have multiple version installed but believe I need to be using the latest, or at least 11.1.0. I have these versions installed:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5 Mar 20  2020 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 29  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-10 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Apr 28  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Mar  9 12:57 /usr/bin/gcc-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 Mar 20  2020 /usr/bin/gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 May 29  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-10 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Apr 28  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Mar  9 12:57 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 Mar 20  2020 /usr/bin/gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 May 29  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-10 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Apr 28  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Mar  9 12:57 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Mar 20  2020 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May 29  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-10 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Apr 28  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar  9 12:57 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9
```

If that's the issue, how can I specify which version of gcc to use? Would that happen in the makefile/cmakelist itself, as a path which I need to specify in my environment, or as a flag applied when calling cmake?

Or does the error suggest another solution?

Comment: What is the output of CMake Configuration stage? What is the output of verbose build compilation `cmake --build .. --verbose`?

Comment: I find it strange that the option `-std=c++20` is passed while building a `C` object. To my understanding, it should only apply to `CXX` objects? But I might be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, it sort of is strange--even when I got it working the compiler warned me that it should only really be passed through CXX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you are in a build directory:

You can set CMAKE_C_COMPILER when you run the original call to cmake.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-11 ..
cmake --build .
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer--failure to call gcc-11 was in fact the issue. I managed to run it before reading your answer by a slightly different method:  
$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-11  
$ export CC=/usr/bin/g++-11   
$ cmake --build  
Not exactly the most straightforward but effectively the same result. Thanks again.